# Iptables error :libipt_cgroup.so doesn't exist while using net_cls.classid in net_cls cgroup subsystem

Tags: linux, iptables

In kernel document doc/cgroup/net_cls.txt， it introduces the function of net_cls.classid, and show an example of netfilter (iptables) using this tag to perform actions.
the command of iptables is:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup ! --cgroup 0x100001 -j DROP
```

but, I've got an error:

> iptables v1.4.7: Couldn't load match
>   `cgroup':/lib64/xtables/libipt_cgroup.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

Then, I began to search fo libipt_cgroup.so in the newest version of iptables-1.4.21, but I got noting.

So, I want to know the reason for it, and how to resolve it, thx!

Comment: the latest ( after april -2014) has it